# Capturing apache camel route cxf web response

Tags: xml, web-services, maven, components, apache-camel

I am new to Stack Overflow and Apache Camel routing and am having some trouble. I have created a really simple SOAP web service that takes an XML request that contains some random text and it then returns the same string in a response.

Using Camel I am able to send the request to the web service and get a response (if I use the log component to capture the request/response.

Ideally I would like to send the XML messages (message1.xml, message2.xml, message3.xml) to the webservice and then process them and store the responses in file:src/data/responses/(message1.xml, message2.xml, message3.xml) etc.. I thought it might be as simple as adding an extra step to my route (see below).

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route>
<from uri="file:src/data?noop=true" />
<log loggingLevel="INFO" message="${body}"/>
<to uri="cxf://http://localhost:8181/cxf/webservice?wsdlURL=src/main/resources/META-INF/webservice.wsdl&amp;serviceName={http://carose.com/}EchoServiceImplService&amp;portName={http://carose.com/}EchoServiceImplPort&amp;dataFormat=MESSAGE"/>
<log loggingLevel="INFO" message="${body}"/>
<to uri="file:src/data/responses" />
</route>
</camelContext>
```

However, when I run the route using `mvn camel:run` it creates a blank XML file in the /responses/ folder for each message. The following error messages are displayed when executing the route:

```
[           default-workqueue-1] route1                         INFO  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:echoTextResponse xmlns:ns2="http://carose.com/"><return>Hello this is a test 123</return></ns2:echoTextResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
[           default-workqueue-2] route1                         INFO  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:echoTextResponse xmlns:ns2="http://carose.com/"><return>this is another test!</return></ns2:echoTextResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
[           default-workqueue-3] route1                         INFO  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:echoTextResponse xmlns:ns2="http://carose.com/"><return>and another test!</return></ns2:echoTextResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
[           default-workqueue-2] DefaultErrorHandler            ERROR Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-christophersair-lan-53992-1398682968504-0-9 on ExchangeId: ID-christophersair-lan-53992-1398682968504-0-4). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot store file: src/data/responses/message2.xml
```

### Message History

```
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [file://src/data?noop=true                                                     ] [        26]
[route1            ] [log1              ] [log                                                                           ] [         1]
[route1            ] [to1               ] [cxf://http://localhost:8181/cxf/webservice?wsdlURL=src/main/resources/META-INF] [        15]
[route1            ] [log2              ] [log                                                                           ] [         3]
[route1            ] [to2               ] [file:src/data/responses                                                       ] [         5]
```

### Exchange

```
Exchange[
Id                  ID-christophersair-lan-53992-1398682968504-0-4
ExchangePattern     InOnly
Headers             {breadcrumbId=ID-christophersair-lan-53992-1398682968504-0-3, CamelCxfMessage={org.apache.cxf.client=true, org.apache.cxf.message.inbound=true, org.apache.cxf.message.Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS={content-type=[text/xml;charset=UTF-8], Server=[Jetty(7.6.7.v20120910)], transfer-encoding=[chunked]}, Content-Type=text/xml;charset=UTF-8, org.apache.cxf.transport.Conduit=conduit: class org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit2125068082target: http://localhost:8181/cxf/webservice, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionInfoMap={}, org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapVersion=org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.Soap11@48a43495, org.apache.cxf.message.Message.RESPONSE_CODE=200, org.apache.cxf.message.Message.ENCODING=UTF-8}, CamelFileAbsolute=false, CamelFileAbsolutePath=/Users/christopherrose/RedHat/SG Project/webservice-client/camel-wsclient/src/data/message2.xml, CamelFileLastModified=1398259868000, CamelFileLength=337, CamelFileName=message2.xml, CamelFileNameConsumed=message2.xml, CamelFileNameOnly=message2.xml, CamelFileParent=src/data, CamelFilePath=src/data/message2.xml, CamelFileRelativePath=message2.xml, CamelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0, content-type=text/xml;charset=UTF-8, ResponseContext={org.apache.cxf.client=true, org.apache.cxf.message.Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS={content-type=[text/xml;charset=UTF-8], Server=[Jetty(7.6.7.v20120910)], transfer-encoding=[chunked]}, org.apache.cxf.message.inbound=true, Content-Type=text/xml;charset=UTF-8, org.apache.cxf.message.Message.ENCODING=UTF-8, org.apache.cxf.message.Message.RESPONSE_CODE=200, org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapVersion=org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.Soap11@48a43495, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionInfoMap={}, org.apache.cxf.transport.Conduit=conduit: class org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit2125068082target: http://localhost:8181/cxf/webservice}, Server=Jetty(7.6.7.v20120910), transfer-encoding=chunked}
BodyType            sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.HttpInputStream
Body                [Body is instance of java.io.InputStream]
```

]

### Stacktrace

```
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot store file: src/data/responses/message2.xml
at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:269)
at         org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.writeFile(GenericFileProducer.java:277)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.processExchange(GenericFileProducer.java:165)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.process(GenericFileProducer.java:79)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:113)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.access$100(Pipeline.java:43)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline$1.done(Pipeline.java:136)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$InternalCallback.done(CamelInternalProcessor.java:251)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler$1.done(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:410)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor$1.done(InstrumentationProcessor.java:81)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$1.done(SendProcessor.java:123)
at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfClientCallback.handleResponse(CxfClientCallback.java:63)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:856)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1614)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream$1.run(HTTPConduit.java:1129)
at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$3.run(AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java:428)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$AWQThreadFactory$1.run(AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java:353)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: stream is closed
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.ensureOpen(ChunkedInputStream.java:174)
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:673)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3053)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3047)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.writeFileByStream(FileOperations.java:375)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:263)
... 24 more
[           default-workqueue-3] DefaultErrorHandler            ERROR Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-christophersair-lan-53992-1398682968504-0-7 on ExchangeId: ID-christophersair-lan-53992-1398682968504-0-6). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot store file: src/data/responses/message3.xml
```

I am assuming that it maybe unable to retrieve the response and store it in a file or maybe there is something that all might be able to point me in the direction of?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you double check the message2.xml in your src/data directory?

Comment: How to execute the root in fuse ide ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Camel v2.12.2, I did not get an exception, but the file was empty when logging the body content. This is as streams can only be read once, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718403/java-camel-framework-losing-message-body-in-processor/24720257#24720257). Thus, remove the log after consuming the CXF webservice:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="file:src/data?noop=true" />
        <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="${body}"/>
        <to uri="cxf://http://localhost:8181/cxf/webservice?wsdlURL=src/main/resources/META-INF/webservice.wsdl&amp;serviceName={http://carose.com/}EchoServiceImplService&amp;portName={http://carose.com/}EchoServiceImplPort&amp;dataFormat=MESSAGE"/>
        <!-- do not log the body or the file written will be empty
        <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="${body}"/>
        -->
        <to uri="file:src/data/responses?fileName=output.txt" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Beside that, I added the `fileName` option in order to obtain a nice file name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you message2.xml is call a one way service.
Can you double check the message2.xml in your src/data directory? 
If it's one way message or an invalided soap request, you may not get a right input stream you want.

Comment: thanks, I have just tried adding the streamCache = true attribute to the route and this seems to have fixed my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have managed to fix it..

I thought it might have been due to the response not being cached or stored anywhere during the route, causing it to create the blank files (message1.xml, message2.xml and message3.xml). I found that there is a stream caching setting that you can set, so I turned that on and it is now creating all three files with the correct XML responses in. See my route XML below:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route streamCache="true">
    <from uri="file:src/data?noop=true" />
    <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="${body}"/>
    <to uri="cxf://http://localhost:8181/cxf/webservice?wsdlURL=src/main/resources/META-INF/webservice.wsdl&amp;serviceName={http://carose.com/}EchoServiceImplService&amp;portName={http://carose.com/}EchoServiceImplPort&amp;dataFormat=MESSAGE"/>
    <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="${body}"/>
    <to uri="file:src/data/responses" />
</route>
```

Thanks for the suggestions :)